# JQuery function doesn't print out anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to let it work this jquery function but without any results. Here is it. It receive from setmap (a servlet) a list formatted in json. I'm totally sure I get the list but unfortunately I don't see the map appearing in the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#airports").click(function(){

        $.getJSON('setmap', function(list) {       

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 2,
                mapTypeId: new google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };

            $('.grid_12').append($("<div id='mapCanvas'></div>"));

            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);  

            if(list.length > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
                {
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(list[i].latitude,list[i].longitude);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map
                    });
                }    
            } 

        });

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<article>
  <section class="grid_12"></section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
```

`mapCanvas` is not defined.  It might implicitly work in some browsers because some browsers will define a symbol for every ID, but you really shouldn't rely on that.  I'm assuming you want to pass the DOM element there (that's what google maps wants), so you can do that more explicitly like this:

```
var mapCanvas = ($("<div id='mapCanvas'></div>").appendTo('.grid_12'))[0];
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
```

Since you haven't provided a runnable demonstration, there may be other errors too.

Comment: I have added what you have suggested unforuntately it doesn't work...I have tried to print console.log('Hi') inside callback function and I don't get anything so it does means what?

Comment: @eng_mazzy - Then, it probably means that your `$.getJSON()` function isn't working.  You may need to switch to `$.ajax()` and define an `error` handler for `$.getJSON()` or add a .fail() handler so you can see what error is being returned.

Comment: ok then  I'm going to do it now.let's see what error or errors I get

Comment: ok I write the following error function error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(ajaxOptions + " " + xhr.responseText);
            }

Comment: @eng_mazzy - `console.log()` the 2nd and 3rd arguments passed to the error handler to see what it says.

Comment: @eng_mazzy - I'd suggest you look in the networking tab and see what is going across the wire on the return.  You need to dive into why you are getting an error and without being able to debug your code ourselves, it's a bit tough for us to know.  The 2nd and 3rd arguments probably give you more info than just "error".